# Quick Linear Approximation Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

So I was given the following prompt:

"Let $f$ be a differentiable function such that $f(3)=2.345$ and $f'(x)=ln(x^2+1)$. What is the value of $f(5)$?"

This was a bit confusing, since in my professor's class we're talking about integrals, I assumed that you took the integral of $f'(x)$ to give you $f(x)$, but after doing this process, I found an answer that was nowhere close to the given choices. After doing some digging I found that linear approximation might work here too, so I'm really lost. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to integrate $f'(x)$ which can be done through integration by parts. The anti derivative has a $C$ which can be determined with given info

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

I would start by integrating it by parts
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \int\ln(x^{2}+1)\mathrm{d}x = x\ln(x^{2}+1) - \int\frac{2x^{2}}{x^{2}+1}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
Then we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\frac{2x^{2}}{x^{2}+1} = 2 - \frac{2}{x^{2}+1} \Rightarrow \int\frac{2x^{2}}{x^{2}+1}\mathrm{d}x = 2x - 2\arctan(x) + c
\end{align*}
Finally, one has that
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \int\ln(x^{2}+1)\mathrm{d}x = x\ln(x^{2}+1) - 2x + 2\arctan(x) - c
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hm, I got a similar integral when I took a stab at it, but when I plugged $5$ into the equation I got an answer that was nowhere near some of the choices I was given.

Comment: @joe. You must use $f(3)$ to fix $c$